# I don't know what is happening with python zlib

Tags: python, zlib

```
comp = z.compress("iasdfhuisahfiiunajsdfijniunadinfianlisdnf", 1)
z.decompress(comp, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -2 while preparing to decompress data: inconsistent stream state
```

It seem to be a zlib bug, but I want to be sure I'm not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/28641731/6250071

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful, the "1" in `z.compress("iasdfhuisahfiiunajsdfijniunadinfianlisdnf", 1)` is not the same as the "1" in `z.decompress(comp, 1)`.

Indeed the first one is the compression level, (from 0 to 9), whereas the second one is the window size, which you can omit.

Hence, you can do the following :

```
>>> import zlib as z
>>> comp = z.compress("iasdfhuisahfiiunajsdfijniunadinfianlisdnf", 1)
>>> z.decompress(comp)
'iasdfhuisahfiiunajsdfijniunadinfianlisdnf'
```

You can find additional informations [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#module-zlib)

Answer (score 1):

`zlib.decompress` does not take a compression level parameter. The optional second parameter means [something completely different](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress).

```
zlib.decompress(comp)
```